# How to stop javascript counter at specific number

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I have this javascript code for tampermonkey that works on Amazon. What it does is just counts up your gift card balance and makes it look like I am getting money. I want to know if it is possible to make it stop at a specific number.

```
var oof = document.getElementById("gc-ui-balance-gc-balance-value");

var lastCount = localStorage.getItem("lastCount");

oof.innerText = '$' + lastCount || "$10000";

function animateValue(id) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    var current = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("lastCount")) || 10000;

    setInterval(function () {
        var nextCount = current++;
        localStorage.setItem("lastCount", nextCount);
        obj.innerText = '$' + nextCount;
    }, 0.1);
}

animateValue('gc-ui-balance-gc-balance-value')
```

Comment: `setInteval` returns a unique ID which you can clear with `clearInterval(<ID>);` just memorize it and call it if the counter is as high as you need it to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) inside your setInterval callback so each time the callback is called, you can check if the new count has reached your threshold and clear the timer if it does.

If you check the value outside of the callback, the logic won't be called at each count increment.

```
function animateValue(id) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    var current = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("lastCount")) || 10000;

    var interval = null;
    var maxCount = 1000;
    var callback = function() {
        var nextCount = current++;
        if (nextCount === maxCount) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        localStorage.setItem("lastCount", nextCount);
        obj.innerText = '$' + nextCount;
    }
    interval = setInterval(callback, 0.1);
}
```

Here is a demo:

```js
let current = 0;
let interval = null;

const callback = () => {
    let nextCount = current++;
    console.log(nextCount);
    if (nextCount === 5) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}

interval = setInterval(callback, 100);
```

Comment: @Jmuse.v2, I replaced the arrow function by a regular function and I replaced let/const by var, does it work now ?

Comment: Can you try to make it go with the rest of my code or something because I don't know where to put it. Also maxCount is not defined

Comment: @Jmuse.v2, yes you have to define maxCount, this is only an example, and I integrated it in your animateValue function already

Comment: When I got the new code from you I just added the "animateValue('gc-ui-balance-gc-balance-value')" at the bottom and it started to work! Thanks Very Much!

Answer (score 0):

May be by clearing the interval when `current` reaches to a specific value like this

```
function animateValue(id) {
  // rest of the code
  let interval = setInterval(function() {
    var nextCount = current++;
    localStorage.setItem("lastCount", nextCount);
    obj.innerText = '$' + nextCount;
  }, 0.1);

  if (current === requiredVal) {
    clearInterval(interval)
  }
  return current;
}
```